# Retrieve build number or artifacts of downstream build in Jenkins

Tags: hudson, jenkins, parameterized

I have a job (call it BIGJOB) in Jenkins; several of the build steps are to trigger builds on other jobs (call them SMALLJOB) using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) then wait for them to complete.  What I need to do  is retrieve artifacts from the triggered build on SMALLJOB.

Originally, I thought I could use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to retrieve the artifacts from the "last build" of the triggered SMALLJOB.  And this does work reliably when there is only one SMALLJOB running at a time.

But I've got multiple BIGJOBs running, all triggering multiple SMALLJOBs so that using the "last build" is unreliable of two SMALLJOBs finish at the same time.

Is there a more reliable way of getting the artifacts from the specific downstream job?  If I could just get the build number, I could use curl to get the artifacts.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just if any (else) stumples accross this question in the future:

When using the Parameterized Trigger Plugin as a build step, then if the trigger is configured with the "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" enabled, the following Environment variables are made available for further build steps:

- LAST_TRIGGERED_JOB_NAME="Last project started"
- TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_{project name}="Last build number triggered"

**from version 2.17 onwards**

- TRIGGERED_JOB_NAMES="Comma separated list of all triggered projects"
- TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBERS_{project name}="Comma separated list of build numbers triggered"
- TRIGGERED_BUILD_RESULT_{project name}="Last triggered build result of project"
- TRIGGERED_BUILD_RESULT_{project name}RUN{build number}="Result of triggered build for build number"
- TRIGGERED_BUILD_RUN_COUNT_{project name}="Number of builds triggered for the project"

See more info on the plugin website - linked in the question.

Comment: is it possible to use them in a pipeline?

Answer (score 10):

Found my own answer.  Not as easy as plugin or an already-set variable, but it works.

Use the Jenkins XML API with depth=1 (very import to get the URLs fully traversed and all information available) and XPATH.  Here is a sample of the URL I used:

```
http://jenkins/job/SMALLJOB/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/freeStyleProject/build[action/cause/upstreamProject="%JOB_NAME%" and action/cause/upstreamBuild=%BUILD_ID%]/number/text()
```

This would return the build number of the right SMALLJOB (the one started by THIS BIGJOB).  Then use that number in http download from Jenkins to get the archived build files.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this functions :

[Jenkins Build](https://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/build.html) where you can find :

> jenkinsapi.api.block_until_complete(jenkinsurl, jobs, maxwait=12000, interval=30, raise_on_timeout=True, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_artifacts(jenkinsurl, jobid=None, build_no=None, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_build(jenkinsurl, jobname, build_no, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_latest_build(jenkinsurl, jobname, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_latest_complete_build(jenkinsurl, jobname, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_latest_test_results(jenkinsurl, jobname, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_nested_view_from_url(url, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.get_view_from_url(url, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.grab_artifact(jenkinsurl, jobid, artifactid, targetdir, username=None, password=None)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.install_artifacts(artifacts, dirstruct, installdir, basestaticurl)
>
> jenkinsapi.api.search_artifact_by_regexp(jenkinsurl, jobid, artifactRegExp, username=None, password=None)