# How to get a the build number of a non-blocking downstream build in the parent build in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a build job X have as post-build step a 'trigger to a parametrized build on other projects' (project Y). I would like to have a link (i.e. the build number) to the downstream build. I'm using the Parameterized Trigger Plugin as a build step but to configure the trigger with the "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" is not an option for me.

Is there a way to have the build number to the downstream build? I agree this information to be available just when the downstream build is finished. I agree also to use other plugins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve build number or artifacts of downstream build in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133027/retrieve-build-number-or-artifacts-of-downstream-build-in-jenkins)

Comment: @Behe, I saw that question, is not a duplicate because to "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" is not an option for me.

Comment: Do you happen to have found a solution for this? I'm interested in the same functionality :).

Comment: @ionela.voinescu nope :(